# Is there any way to add color to inner of 'O' in CSS?

Tags: css

Actually i have an issue, when i need to add color to the text that written and fill color into the letter 'O'. Is there any way to add color to inner of 'O' in CSS?

Comment: If not text, Create a circle using `border-radius: 50%` and then fill color using background.

Comment: do you mean different color, or just fill "O" with same color as text?

Comment: Yeah exactly @Pepo_rasta, i mean to fill different color to the text that contain 'o' character in the sentence. Thanks